# How do i pass the parameter in Jasmine Unit Test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

How do i pass below list of parameters to the below unit test spec in jasmine?

> **params -**  "userId" : "user1", "location" : "london", "salary" : "33333", "hobby" : "swimming"

This is an approximate unit test spec and not an accurate one.

```
describe("my jasmine test suite", function() {

   var params,
       myController

   beforeEach(function() {
     module('myApp');
     mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockService',['serviceCall']);

     module(function($provide) {

          $provide.value('myService',mockService);

       });

     inject(function($controller,$q,_$rootscope_) {
     mockService.serviceCall.and.callFake(function(srvcname,mthdname,params)
       {  
         var resData = {};
        if(mthdname === 'servicecall')
         {
            // assign the mockdata
          }
            return mockData;
     });

     $rootscope = _$rootscope_;
     myScope = $rootscope.$new();

    myController = $controller('myController',{$scope:myscope});
 });

});

it('my test spec',function() {

    expect(mockService.serviceCall).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(myscope.searchRslt[0]).toBe(mockData.searchRslt[0]);
    $rootScope.$digest();

});

});
```

I am not sure how do pass the parameter to the jasmine unit test spec

Answer (score 0):

If you do this...

```
mockService.serviceCall.and.callFake(function(srvcname,mthdname,params)
{  
    var mockData = {};
    if(mthdname === 'servicecall')
    {
        // assign the mockdata
        mockData.searchRslt = new Array();
        mockData.searchRslt.push({ "userId" : "user1", "location" : "london", "salary" : "33333", "hobby" : "swimming"});
    }
    return mockData;
 });
```

... the result of `mockData.searchRslt[0]` would be `Object {userId: "user1", location: "london", salary: "33333", hobby: "swimming"}`

Since we don't know the shape of `myscope.searchRslt[0]`, it's hard to say if that's exactly what you need, but it should give you the idea how to approach it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and let you know. Do you have any online example where params has been passed to the unit test methods?